# Set hadoop configuration values on spark-submit command line

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

We want to set the `aws` parameters that from code would be done via the `SparkContext`:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", vault.user)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", vault.key)
```

However we have a custom Spark launcher framework that requires all the custom Spark configurations to be done via `--conf` parameters to the `spark-submit` command line.

Is there a way to "notify" the SparkContext to set `--conf` values to the `hadoopConfiguration` and not to its general `SparkConf` ?  Looking for something along the lines of

```
spark-submit --conf hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key $vault.user --conf hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key $vault.key
```

or

```
spark-submit --conf hadoopConfiguration.fs.s3a.access.key $vault.user --conf hadoopConfiguration.fs.s3a.access.key $vault.key
```

Comment: `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=value`

Comment: @vanza -Yes! i was trying to remember that . Please add as answer

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to prefix Hadoop configs with `spark.hadoop.` in the command line (or `SparkConf` object). For example:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=value
```

Comment: Yay! I was looking for it! It's working! That's what SO is for (-:

Comment: And this ends 2 days of searching. Thank you!

Comment: they do not recommend using `s3a://` anymore https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html. Do you know how to setup to use `s3://`?